# Magento Product and Category page is not working

Tags: php, magento

I have hosted magento on the windows server, when I am accessing it is working fine by url [Anzonline](http://sites.demopoint.in/anzonline/) but when I Click any menu, category or products from home page it not working. check url [Category link](http://sites.demopoint.in/anzonline/Index.php/drinks.html) when i check that page is working or not then i check url [enter link description here](http://sites.demopoint.in/anzonline/Index.php/catalog/category/view/id/4) it is working fine.

I had set Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites = 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

If you have magento on window in that case your .htaccess file will not work. So in this case your url rewrite also not work.

Try to go through with this document(http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/225273/), if you want to make url rewrite working on windows/iis.